# Python `socket.getaddrinfo` taking 5 seconds about 0.1% of requests

Tags: python, sockets, dns, python-requests

Running Python on a Django project which communicates with various web-services, we have an issue that occasionally requests are taking around 5 seconds instead of their usual < 100 ms.

I've narrowed this down to time taken in the `socket.getaddrinfo` function - this is being called by `requests` when we connect to external services, but it also appears to effect the default Django connection to the Postgres database box in the cluster. When we restart `uwsgi` after a deployment the first requests that come in will take 5 seconds to send a response. I also believe that our celery tasks are taking 5 seconds on a regular basis, but I've not added statsd timer tracking to them yet.

I've written some code to reproduce the issue:

```
import socket
import timeit

def single_dns_lookup():
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    socket.getaddrinfo('stackoverflow.com', 443)
    end = timeit.default_timer()
    return int(end - start)

timings = {}

for _ in range(0, 10000):
    time = single_dns_lookup()
    try:
        timings[time] += 1
    except KeyError:
        timings[time] = 1

print timings
```

Typical results are `{0: 9921, 5: 79}`

My colleague has already pointed to potential issues around ipv6 lookup times and has added this to the `/etc/gai.conf`:

```
precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100
```

This has definitely improved lookups from non-Python programs such as `curl` which we use, but not from Python itself. The server boxes are running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and I'm able to reproduce this on a vanilla VM with Python 2.

What steps can I take to improve the performance of all Python lookups so that they can take < 1s?

Comment: How about caching results and renew them using celery or something like that?

Comment: it sounds like your dns resolver is slow, give ncsd a try?

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov What would you suggest for the cache? And how would you suggest that the cache should be updated and kept hot so that Python server code *never* has to run a slow request except when updating the cache?

Comment: @georgexsh I'm not sure how nscd would help - the first request that is not cached would still take 5s. And after the cached value expires then the first request that goes through the resolver would take 5s again. This would just reduce the percentage of slow requests and not remove them entirely right?

Comment: @jamesc redis maybe? And for updating celery

Comment: Instead of using port 443, try using 0 and see if that help anyways? Also do you have redis available? can that be used for caching of these results?

Comment: Have you tried to disable the IPv6 stack altogether with  `sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1`, and check if that fixes your issue ?

If yes, then most probably your `python` is linked to a version of glibc (or statically compiled against) which does not respect gai.conf.

Comment: can't reproduce it locally in vagrant ubuntu/xenial64

Comment: Consider using `collections.Counter` instead of rolling your own with `KeyError`

Comment: @TarunLalwani Changing the port to 0 does not help.

Comment: @zeppelin Disabling the IPv6 stack didn't help. This makes me wonder if the issue with other non-Python programs I mention has really been solved by the `gai.conf` tweak.

Comment: @jamesc, see if the answer I posted is of any help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

5s is a default timeout to DNS lookup.

[You can lower that.](https://serverfault.com/questions/562079/adjusting-how-long-linux-takes-to-fail-over-to-backup-dns-server-listed-in-resol)

Your real problem is probably (silent) UDP packets drop on the network though.

**Edit:** Experiment with [resolution over TCP](https://serverfault.com/questions/762003/how-to-configure-linux-to-use-tcp-for-dns-queries). Never done that. Might help you.

Answer (score 4):

There are two things that can be done. One is that you don't query the IPV6 address, this can be done by monkey patching getaddrinfo

```
orig_getaddrinfo = socket.getaddrinfo

def _getaddrinfo(host, port, family=0, type=0, proto=0, flags=0):
    return orig_getaddrinfo(host, port, socket.AF_INET, type, proto, flags)

socket.getaddrinfo = _getaddrinfo
```

Next you can also use a ttl based cache to cache the result. You can use `cachepy` package for the same.

```
from cachetools import cached
import socket
import timeit
from cachepy import *
# or from cachepy import Cache

cache_with_ttl = Cache(ttl=600) # ttl given in seconds

orig_getaddrinfo = socket.getaddrinfo

# @cached(cache={})
@cache_with_ttl
def _getaddrinfo(host, port, family=0, type=0, proto=0, flags=0):
    return orig_getaddrinfo(host, port, socket.AF_INET, type, proto, flags)

socket.getaddrinfo = _getaddrinfo

def single_dns_lookup():
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    socket.getaddrinfo('stackoverflow.com', 443)
    end = timeit.default_timer()
    return int(end - start)

timings = {}

for _ in range(0, 10000):
    time = single_dns_lookup()
    try:
        timings[time] += 1
    except KeyError:
        timings[time] = 1

print (timings)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would first try to understand the root cause of the slowness before building a cache or monkeypatching `socket.getaddrinfo`. Are your nameservers configured correctly in `/etc/resolv.conf`? Are you seeing packet loss on the network?

If you're experiencing loss that's outside your control, running a caching server (`nscd`) will mask but not completely eliminate the problem.